# When installing various desktop environments, how can one prevent user interactions requesting a selection of display managers like LightDM and GDM3?

Tags: package-management, lightdm, gdm, display-manager

I have a Bash setup script for Ubuntu. It is intended to be designed to minimise the user interactions needed to get to a fully set up system.

In the script, there might be commands like the following:

```
sudo apt -y install lxde-common
sudo apt -y install ubuntu-mate-desktop
sudo apt -y install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

I have observed that the user is prompted, after installation of each of these, to choose a display manager, such as LightDM or GDM3. How can one suppress this interaction and have the system stick with whatever the current display manager is?

Comment: You have to modify the installation scripts in the relevant `.deb` packages, which also means repacking these. Not sure if you really want this.

Comment: @Rinzwind Sort of - It's very close.  This question says "whatever the *current* display manager is".  Not sure if that makes it a duplicate or not, personally.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds well that just means the 1ts part needs to be a command that fetches it ;)

Comment: Thank you for the input. The referenced post does indeed provide a solution.